# How can I override the string programmatically in forum topic list?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using the Forum module in Drupal 7. I want to change `"Topic"` with `"foo"`, for example, in the *General discussion* forum page.

> [image]

#### Where did I search for this

1. I did check the template in the forum module file and for this page it is `forum-topic-list.tpl.php`. There I found that, it is printed by following code,

   ```
   <thead>
       <tr><?php print $header; ?></tr>
   </thead>
   ```

   And in the description, the following statement has been provided.

   > Available variables:
   >
   > - $header: The table header. This is pre-generated with click-sorting information. If you need to change this, see `template_preprocess_forum_topic_list()`.

   Hence, there is nothing called "Topic" which I can just change as this header coming from the $header.

   Now, I did check [`template_preprocess_forum_topic_list()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21forum%21forum.module/function/template_preprocess_forum_topic_list/7.x) but it does not have provision to Change "Topic" string.
2. Lastly, I did check the forum.module where I found the following function starting at line 914.

   ```
    function forum_get_topics($tid, $sortby, $forum_per_page) {
      global $user, $forum_topic_list_header;

      $forum_topic_list_header = array(
        NULL,
        array('data' => t('Topic'), 'field' => 'f.title'),
        array('data' => t('Replies'), 'field' => 'f.comment_count'),
        array('data' => t('Last reply'), 'field' => 'f.last_comment_timestamp'),
     );
   ```

   Now, in the above function you can see `t('Topic')`. I could simply replace it with `t('foo')`, but I think this is not the right way.

Any suggestion, how can I override this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the code in `template_preprocess_forum_topic_list()`, you can see the `$header` is built with the global variable `$forum_topic_list_header`. It is possible to override it.

Most of the code here is copy from `template_preprocess_forum_topic_list()`. Only the part of code for building `$header` is needed.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_forum_topic_list().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_forum_topic_list(&$variables) {
  global $forum_topic_list_header;
  $forum_topic_list_header[1]['data'] = t('foo'); // Change "Topic" string

  // Create the tablesorting header.
  $ts = tablesort_init($forum_topic_list_header);
  $header = '';
  foreach ($forum_topic_list_header as $cell) {
    $cell = tablesort_header($cell, $forum_topic_list_header, $ts);
    $header .= _theme_table_cell($cell, TRUE);
  }
  $variables['header'] = $header;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is changing the "Topic" to "foo". But I would like to know, how did you determine this part `$forum_topic_list_header[1]['data']`, as this part is not available in that `hook`, I mean from where did you arrive on this? Thanks

Comment: @CodeNext What I did is to read code. It sounds stupid but it works :(

Comment: Okk, so we need to trace it back, and apply our code where we want to change the applications. So, this you knows, might be you would have played a lot with codes. But is there a way/module, So the non-coders can get a idea from which function it is originating, which path it is following and what hook we can apply? Or we learn it by playing with it only..:)

Comment: Ahhhh...I understand it is hard for beginners. So that's why Drupal is hard :( in fact, my way is a little bit complicated because I would like to run in the same way as core does. Some others may just replace the string `$variables['header'] = str_replace(t('Topic'), t('foo'), $variables['header'])`.

Comment: I have one question. Instead of `$forum_topic_list_header[1]['data'] = t('foo');` if I take that part as it is form code, like, `$forum_topic_list_header = array(
    NULL,
    array('data' => t('foo'), 'field' => 'f.title'),
    array('data' => t('Replies'), 'field' => 'f.comment_count'),
    array('data' => t('Last reply'), 'field' => 'f.last_comment_timestamp'),
  );` Will it be right thing to do?

Comment: @CodeNext I think it is okay. I don't know why Drupal defines that as global variable. Maybe they plan to use it in other places.

Comment: @CodeNext haha..opensource project is always like that. Sometimes you have to guess why the do in this way... Orz

Comment: Rightly said. And other thing, sometimes too easy, too straight does not give interest and thrill. So, happy with drupal..:)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

Comment: + 1, Yes, this is the option, No doubt. Even before posting question I did found this, and it is working well, but I am keeping this as a second option, just currently I am trying to do things hook-way. Again no doubt this is the right module for changing the t('string'). Thanks

Comment: @CodeNext : your prior comment is perfectly ok/acceptable. But I think you should also somehow mention that in your actual question. Typically "programatically" is added to the title and/or question content to make that clear. Just a suggestion, not more then that ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, Thanks for pointing out. It was needed.